# Process decimal escape in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I have a file of strings one per line in which non-ascii characters have been escaped with decimal code points. One example line is:

`mj\\195\\164ger`

(The double backslashes are in the file exactly as printed)

I would like to process this string to produce

`mjäger`

. Conventionally, python uses hexadecimal escapes rather than decimal escapes (e.g., the above string would be written as `mj\xc3\xa4ger`, which python can decode:

```
>>> by=b'mj\xc3\xa4ger'
>>> by.decode('utf-8')
'mjäger'
```

Python, however, doesn't recognize the decimal escape right away.

I have written a method that correctly manipulates the strings to produce hexadecimal escapes, but these escapes are themselves escaped. How can I get python to process these hexadecimal escapes to create the final string?

```
import re

hexconst=["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
escapes=re.compile(r"\\[0-9]{3}")
def dec2hex(matchobj):
    dec=matchobj.group(0)
    dec=int(dec[1:])
    digit1=dec//16 #integer division
    digit2=dec%16 
    hex="\\x" + hexconst[digit1] + hexconst[digit2]
    return hex

line=r'mj\195\164ger'
print(escapes.sub(dec2hex,line)) #Outputs mj\xc3\xa4ger
```

What is the final step I'm missing to convert the output of the above from `mj\xc3\xa4ger` to `mjäger`? Thanks!

Comment: print(escapes.sub(dec2hex,line)) give the output mj\xc3\xa4ger, but it's store as mj\\xc3\\xa4ger in the memory. I will delete my answer, it's similar to Tim's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier. `re.sub()` can take a callback function instead of a replacement string as an argument:

```
>>> import re
>>> line=r'mj\195\164ger'
>>> def replace(match):
...     return chr(int(match.group(1)))

>>> regex = re.compile(r"\\(\d{1,3})")
>>> new = regex.sub(replace, line)
>>> new
'mj\xc3\xa4ger'
>>> print new
mjäger
```

In Python 3, strings are Unicode strings, so if you're working with encoded input (like UTF-8 encoded content), then you need to use the proper type which is `bytes`:

```
>>> line = rb'mj\195\164ger'
>>> regex = re.compile(rb"\\(\d{1,3})")
>>> def replace(match):
...     return int(match.group(1)).to_bytes(1, byteorder="big")

>>> new = regex.sub(replace, line)
>>> new
b'mj\xc3\xa4ger'
>>> print(new.decode("utf-8"))
mjäger
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim, I see that this works in Python2, but in Python 3, I get ```mjÃ¤ger```. It seems to process the two escapes separately into two latin-1 characters instead of one unicode character. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I had overlooked the Python 3 tag. My apologies. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I didn't realize regexs could be run against bytes objects. That makes it much easier. I was also foolishly trying to avoid reading in the file as bytes, but I've changed that now and everything is working great. Thank you again for your help.